# How to extract input or output variables from a different function as a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am creating a function in matlab which extracts data out of different functions.
I have 6 different functions which are really basic. My goal in the function I am building is to extract the input\output variables as a cell array and display the results in a structure.
For example , I extracted the name of the function to a structure.

```
% This function extracts the name of the function in the function path , as
% well it gives information on the input and output variables
function info=extractInfo(functionPath)
% A simple function which returns the path of the function(p) , the name
% (name) and the extension (e)
function name=getFuncName(funcPath)
[p,name,e]=fileparts(funcPath);
end
% Get the name of the function
name=getFuncName(functionPath);

input=????
%insert into struct form
info=struct('functionName',name);

end
```

Comment: Do you know how many output arguments the functions produce?

Comment: you can use nargin and nargout to get the number of input and output variables respectively but you need a function handle to do it, you can parse the m-file as well, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431577/how-do-i-retrieve-the-names-of-function-parameters-in-matlab