# How to get inputs and outputs from an user defined function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get the names of inputs and outputs of a function that I've defined **while outside the function**. In other words, I can't make any change inside the function. I could not find any built-in function that does this. Is there a function that gives details or summary of a function.

For example, `myfunc.m` file is like below and I'm calling this function in another script.

```
function [out1, out2] = myfunc(input1, input2, input3)
operations
end
```

I need to get the strings `'out1', 'out2', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3'`

I'm using **Matlab R2018a**.

Comment: For inputs: [`inputname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html). For outputs I don't know. See also [`functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html). But I consider it bad practice if a function wants to know the name of its input or output arguments. Do you really need that?

Comment: I need to get names of inputs and outputs from outside of the function

Comment: and if I call it like this: [outA, outB] = myfunc(inputA, inputB, inputC), do you still want  'out1', 'out2', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3'?

Comment: yes, it works but I should not make any change in the function as I said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the names of function parameters in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431577/how-do-i-retrieve-the-names-of-function-parameters-in-matlab)

Comment: Please share **why** you need this. This is highly uncommon practice, and likely you *actual* problem is easier to solve without this step.

Comment: Dear Sardar Usama, the code in the link that you gave has worked. Thank you so much. I could not find how to accept your comment as the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inputname for the input, for output there is no straightforward solution but you can try [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/142733-equivalent-of-inputname-for-output-variables)

Comment: Can I learn inputs of the function from outside of the function? I don't want to change the function..

Comment: before running the function or while it is running? before, the only thing to do is analize the code .m file. while it is running you can use evalin or asignin to send thing in or get stuff out, but his is a shaky thing to do. You can share the function, it'll help us understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I have updated the question, please look at that again.

Answer (score 0):

If your allowed to make changes in the `myfunc.m` file, I can suggest you try something like:

```
function [out1, out2] = myfunc(input1, input2, input3)
% 'out1', 'out2', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3'

operations

end
```

Then in the other script (e.g. test.m):

```
% stuff...
help myfunc
% things....
```

It will return

> `'out1', 'out2', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3'`

---

If your allowed to make changes in the `myfunc.m` file, you can also try:

```
function [out1, out2, string] = myfunc(input1, input2, input3)

operations

string = ["out1", "out2", "input1", "input2", "input3"];

end
```

And in the script

```
[~,~,string] = myfunc(1, 1, 1)
```

It will return:

```
string = 
1×5 string array

    "out1"    "out2"    "input1"    "input2"    "input3"
```

---

**EDIT**: Since your edits, you are not allowed to intervene in the `myfunc.m` file, but you want to read the first line of the function, you can try commands [`open`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/open.html) or [`edit`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/edit.html).

In the other script, write `open myfunc` or `edit myfunc` and it will open the file in a new tab, and you will be able to read it.

Comment: It gave: 

myfunc is a function.

out1 = myfunc(input1, input2)

Comment: Did you write the comment `% 'out1', 'out2', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3'` under the function name, like I did?

Comment: Can I enter the function and read the first line? After that I may find the names of inputs and outputs.